# Overloading operator ->* in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, c++03

I have my own smart pointer implementation and now I am trying to solve the problem of calling the member function by its pointer. I do not provide any get()-like function (actually, I provide an operator->, but I do not want to use it for this purpose).

My question is: what should the signature and the return type of the `operator->*` look like?

Comment: For @OP: [here's a paper](http://aristeia.com/Papers/DDJ_Oct_1999.pdf) that describes **exactly** what you want.

Comment: The "pointer-to-member operators `->*` and `.*`" are described in the C++11 standard in  section 5.5.  They do exist in C++, even if they aren't commonly used.

Comment: Pointer to member, via C++ FAQ: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/dotstar-vs-arrowstar.html

Comment: plus one for link provided by The Paramagnetic Croissant.This is actual implementation user wanted.

Comment: Bah, C++03.  The C++14 version is pretty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For completeness, here's a complete, compilable, minimal example, heavily inspired by this [paper I've linked to](http://aristeia.com/Papers/DDJ_Oct_1999.pdf), and stripped down along with a small usage demo in order to get you started with this:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>


// Our example class on which we'll be calling our member function pointer (MFP)
struct Foo {
    int bar() {
        return 1337;
    }
};

// Return value of operator->* that represents a pending member function call
template<typename C, typename MFP>
struct PMFC {
    const std::unique_ptr<C> &ptr;
    MFP pmf;
    PMFC(const std::unique_ptr<C> &pPtr, MFP pPmf) : ptr(pPtr), pmf(pPmf) {}

    // the 'decltype' expression evaluates to the return type of ((C*)->*)pmf
    decltype((std::declval<C &>().*pmf)()) operator()() {
        return (ptr.get()->*pmf)();
    }
};

// The actual operator definition is now trivial
template<typename C, typename MFP>
PMFC<C, MFP> operator->*(const std::unique_ptr<C> &ptr, MFP pmf)
{
    return PMFC<C, MFP>(ptr, pmf);
}

// And here's how you use it
int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Foo> pObj(new Foo);
    auto (Foo::*pFn)() = &Foo::bar;
    std::cout << (pObj->*pFn)() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `operator->*()` takes two arguments:

1. The object it is operating on.
2. The member pointer to be applied.

If the member pointer is just access for a data member, the result is straight forward: you can just return a reference to the member. If it is a function, well, things are a bit more complicated: the member access operator needs to return a callable object instead. The callable object takes the appropriate number of arguments and returns the type of the member pointer.

I realize that the original question is tagged with c++03 but doing a "proper" C++03 implementation is a rather lengthy typing exercise: you'll have to what is done conveniently by variadic templates in the code below for each number of arguments. So, this code uses C++11 primarily to show more clearly what's needed and to avoid running through a typing exercise.

Here is a simple "smart" pointer defining `operator->*()`:

```
template <typename T>
class my_ptr
{
    T* ptr;
public:
    my_ptr(T* ptr): ptr(ptr) {}

    template <typename R>
    R& operator->*(R T::*mem) { return (this->ptr)->*mem; }

    template <typename R, typename... Args>
    struct callable;
    template <typename R, typename... Args>
    callable<R, Args...> operator->*(R (T::*mem)(Args...));
};
```

I think for "proper" support it also needs to define `const` versions: that should be quite straight forward so I'm omitting these. There are basically two version:

1. One version taking a pointer to a non-function member which just returns the referenced member for the given pointer.
2. One version taking a pointer to a function member which returns a suitable `callable` object. The `callable` will need to have a function call operator and apply it appropriately.

So, the next thing to define is the `callable` type: it will hold a pointer to the object and a pointer to the member and apply them upon call:

```
#include <utility>
template <typename T>
     template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct my_ptr<T>::callable {
    T* ptr;
    R (T::*mem)(Args...);
    callable(T* ptr, R (T::*mem)(Args...)): ptr(ptr), mem(mem) {}

    template <typename... A>
    R operator()(A... args) const {
        return (this->ptr->*this->mem)(std::forward<A>(args)...);
    }
};
```

Well, that's fairly straight forward. The one tricky bit is the fact that arguments the function call operator is being called with may be different types than those the of the pointer to member. The code above deals with the situation by simply forwarding them.

The missing bit is the factory function for the above `callable` type:

```
template <typename T>
    template <typename R, typename... Args>
my_ptr<T>::callable<R, Args...> my_ptr<T>::operator->*(R (T::*mem)(Args...)) {
    return callable<R, Args...>(this->ptr, mem);
}
```

OK, that's all! This is quite a bit of code using fancy C++11 variadic templates. Typing this stuff out to feed it to a C++03 isn't really something I'd fancy. On the plus side, I *think* these operators can be non-member functions. That is, they could be implemented in a suitable namespace which only contains these operators using and an empty tag-type which a smart pointer type would inherit from. With the tag-tag being a base the operators would be found via ADL and work for all smart pointer. They could, e.g., use `operator->()` to get hold of the pointer needed to construct the `callable`.

Using C++11 it is actually reasonably straight forward to implement support for `operator->*()` independent from any specific smart pointer type. The code below shows the implementation and a simple use. It makes use of the fact that this version can only be found based on ADL (you should never have a using directive or declaration for it) and that smart pointers probably implement `operator->()`: the code uses this function to get hold of the smart pointer's pointer. The `member_access` namespace should probably go into a suitable header simply included by other smart pointers which then just inherit from `member_access::member_acccess_tag` (which can be a `private`(!) base class as that still triggers ADL to look into `member_access`).

```
#include <utility>

namespace member_access
{
    struct member_access_tag {};

    template <typename Ptr, typename R, typename T>
    R& operator->*(Ptr ptr, R T::*mem) {
        return ptr.operator->()->*mem;
    }

    template <typename R, typename T, typename... Args>
    struct callable {
        T* ptr;
        R (T::*mem)(Args...);
        callable(T* ptr, R (T::*mem)(Args...)): ptr(ptr), mem(mem) {}

        template <typename... A>
        R operator()(A... args) const {
            return (this->ptr->*this->mem)(std::forward<A>(args)...);
        }
    };

    template <typename Ptr, typename R, typename T, typename... Args>
    callable<R, T, Args...> operator->*(Ptr ptr, R (T::*mem)(Args...)) {
        return callable<R, T, Args...>(ptr.operator->(), mem);
    }
}

template <typename T>
class my_ptr
    : private member_access::member_access_tag
{
    T* ptr;
public:
    my_ptr(T* ptr): ptr(ptr) {}
    T* operator->() { return this->ptr; }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The two arguments for overloaded operator `->*` should be 1. object of your class, and 2. pointer to member. In the simplest case it means that the overloaded operator should be a member of your class accepting one argument of type pointer-to-member, so for instance for a pointer to member function without parameters it would be:

```
TYPE operator->*(void (YourClass::*mp)());
```

The return type should be callable (in the sense that `operator()` applies to it). It is easiest to show with another class - here you have a complete example:

```
struct Caller {
 void operator()() { cout << "caller"; }
};

struct A {
 void f() { cout << "function f"; }
 Caller operator->*(void (A::*mp)()) { return Caller(); }
};

int main() {
 A a;
 void (A::*mp)() = &A::f;
 (a->*mp)();
 return 0;
}
```

which outputs "caller". In real world you would need to use templates to support various pointer-to-member types. More details you can find in [Scott Meyer's paper](http://www.aristeia.com/Papers/DDJ_Oct_1999.pdf).